# sql create record if exists or update

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my sql statement to achieve the query.

```
insert into courses(course_id,course_name,courses) 
values (1,"bet","3") 
where not exists(25,"admin","it")
```

Comment: provide more information..your question is not complete

Comment: Take a look at the merge command. It allows you to insert or update in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `SELECT` query.

```
INSERT INTO courses (course_id, course_name, courses)
SELECT 1, "bet", "3"
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM courses
    WHERE course_id = 25 AND course_name = "admin" AND courses = "it"
)
```